# Mocking everyauth login in a mocha test - nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, facebook-authentication, everyauth, superagent

I am new to mocha and am trying to get familiar with writing tests in mocha. I have a scenario where I am currently using everyauth to authenticate users using facebook authentication. Thus, I may have a request to an endpoint users/profile which is shown below:

```
router.route('/profile')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    if(req.session.auth) {
      res.json({
        user: req.user.toObject({getters: true})
      });
    } else {
      res.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
      res.json({
        message: 'You need to be logged in to view this information'
      });
    }
  });
```

If I wanted to test this endpoint using mocha and superagent, how would I go about doing so? How will I be able to simulate a login with everyauth using the mocha framework.

I currently have a test that is shown below:

```
  it('should return user information on being logged in', function(done) {
    superagent.get(url + '/users/profile').end(function(err, res) {
      expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
      expect(res.body).to.eql({
          users: // some user object
      });
      done();
    });
  });
```

However, unless I am able to simulate the login, I cannot test whether the correct data is being returned via the call to the endpoint.

Comment: What does a successful auth flow look like? Meaning are you able to simulate a login through everyauth with a tool such as PostMan or fiddler?

Comment: @KJ3 : I am not sure if I fully understand your question but I think this is what you are asking me. A successful auth flow using everyauth module for facebook authentication involves sending a request to auth/facebook which redirects  the user to a facebook login page. On successful login, the user data is passed back to the express/node js app via a callback.

Comment: @KJ3: So my question is, if I want to test an endpoint that needs a user to be authenticated, how do I simulate the action of authenticating the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly one solution to this would be to mock the authentication modules for testing purposes with a mocking/stubbing framework such as the very popular [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) stubs. Sinon lets you "override" a function so that instead of that function running, it returns whatever you want it to return.

Without  being familiar with everyauth, you would want something like this:

```
sinon.stub(everyauth, "authenticateUser").yields(null, {
    user: {
        firstName: 'John',
        // etc.
    }
});
```

Where everyauth is the main object, authenticateUser is the method you want to stub, and yields should return exactly what "authenticateUser" would normally return, so this could return the Facebook User object that is normally returned so you can continue to test the functionality of the app.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I shall try this and let you know how I get along.

Comment: thank you for your help, i have managed to do what I wanted using your answer as a guide. :) My solution can be found here:
https://github.com/kushaldsouza/scrumapp/blob/master/tests/users.js